# fatal error: ruby/config.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, qt, qt4, fedora, korundum

I am trying to install korundum on fedora 17. And during the `$ make` phase I got the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/ruby.h:32:0,
                 from Qt.cpp:49:
/usr/include/ruby/ruby.h:24:25: fatal error: ruby/config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[5]: *** [Qt.lo] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/n/Downloads/korundum-3.5.5/qtruby/rubylib/qtruby'
make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/n/Downloads/korundum-3.5.5/qtruby/rubylib/qtruby'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/n/Downloads/korundum-3.5.5/qtruby/rubylib'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/n/Downloads/korundum-3.5.5/qtruby'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/n/Downloads/korundum-3.5.5'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How can solve this problem? I'm loosing my mind.

Comment: why not installing with yum?

Answer (score -1):

The error message suggests that you need the ruby dev files installed, but do not have them.